# Using SQL LIKE for a search engine in PHP

Tags: php, sql, search

i have a little search engine for searching after CITY and some TAGS that are connected to that city.
you can search for city only, city AND tag, and tag only.

My problem is to get the right search result with the tags involved.

City. 
This can only be like "Stockholm" "New York" and so on from DB.

TAGS. 
But this one has more tags in its table, like CITYTAG -> "Volvo, Saab, BMW, Volkswagen, "
Every tag is devided by a comma.

the input will be like:
.../sajt.php?SearchCITY=stockholm&SearchTAG=volvo

this is my code so far:

```
   SELECT * FROM city 
    WHERE CITYNAME LIKE '%" . $SearchCITY . "%' OR CITYTAG LIKE '%" . $SearchTAG . "%'
```

how do i put this together?
So it can handle the search right!
Because when i search for Volvo, i dont wont Volkswagen to come up.

Comment: Wouldn't AND instead of OR be better?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic. You want matches only where city *and* tag match or when *either* matches or...? Should `ag` hit Volkswagen?

Comment: `Every tag is devided by a comma.` This is a problem and should be changed.

Comment: Can you please add a better example so that is clear which logic you would like to have? Different database reords and which of them you expect.

Comment: @paqogomez - So that others may learn better, could you elaborate on why it's a problem?

Comment: Sure @GigaWatt.  In a relational database, storing comma separated values in a field negates _all_ the value of the relation database.  Its also crazy difficult to maintain.  An easy example in this case is wanting to clean up the tags and remove one.  This happens all the time on sites like this one.  Best to put it the values in another table and join to them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$tags = str_replace('|',',',$citytag);
$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM city WHERE CITYNAME='$cityname' AND CITYTAG='$tags'");
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cityname, substring('Volvo, Saab, BMW, Volkswagen,',Locate('Volvo','Volvo, Saab, BMW, Volkswagen,'),length('Volvo')) as citytag 
FROM city 
WHERE CITYNAME LIKE '%" . $SearchCITY . "%' OR CITYTAG LIKE '%" . $SearchTAG . "%';

change this sql using OR and AND conditions to fit your search combinations
```